# Conditional formatting based on largest value in range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet with a count of user logons at 3 different sites. I want to conditionally format a column (E) to output the location, based on the largest value in cell range columns B to D, example:

```
   A   |       B      |      C       |       D      |     E
Name   | Site1Logins  | Site2Logins  |  Site3Logins | MainSite?
User1  |     200      |      0       |      50      |   Site1
User2  |      0       |      20      |      120     |   Site3
User3  |     10       |      80      |      40      |   Site2
```

So, E should automatically populate the site based on the largest value of columns B, C & D. Is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after isn't conditional formatting - that would be changing the Format of a cell rather than it's value.

A formula that would work for this task is:

`="Site"&MATCH(MAX(B2:D2),B2:D2,0)`

Though there are many ways in which you could achieve this

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.
Sorry for confusing the terminology.